# Python generic inheritance and vscode intellisense (MSLS)

Tags: python, generics, visual-studio-code

I was expecting the autocomplete to tell me that obj is `str` type (from the base class), but it says `Model`. Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Is this with Jedi or the Microsoft Language Server? Whichever one it is you will need to file a bug there.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the `TypeVar` as `'Model'`. You should instead use `def save(self, obj: str)` as your function definition.

Comment: well, it is a generic function and I don't want to hardcode `str` in it.